# Comment Wont Appear

Tags: channel-entries, comments, comment-form

I copied my comment forms directly from my blog posts so I can use them also for comments on trainer pages but the same code that was working before wont work with my new channel.

[Link to example (droplr)](http://d.pr/VZvn)

Is there anything I'm forgetting to get this to work? If I remove the channel variable from both, nothing will change with the comment:entries, but comment:form will display.  I can't seem to get these to display with the **personal_trainer_directory** channel

[Current Channel Settings](http://d.pr/sYS1)

Comment: Is this code appearing in a single entry template (with a URL that specifies an entry)?

Comment: @DerekHogue yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the form doesn't know which entry to associate the comment with.

Try setting either the `entry_id=""` or `url_title=""` parameters on the `{exp:comment:form}` tag.

Comment: Hey Anna! I gtried this, http://d.pr/2Uod but seems its posting the comment to every entry instead of the 1.. but i can see the form and the comments now but its posting to all the trainer entries..

Comment: Can you post the full template code to www.pastie.org? Try hardcoding an entry_id or url_title. What happens?

Comment: I added the `url_title="{last_segment}"` to the comment loop so it would be on that and the form and it seems to be working now! thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, it needs to be on the comment tag too. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: This just saved my butt, working with structure and it looks like I now need this parameter. Thanks Anna.

Answer (score 0):

Joe,

You'll need to make sure that comments are on for that channel, and that you're visiting that page as a Single Entry page.  That is, where the URL contains either the Entry ID or URL Title of an entry that allows comments.

Comment: I checked the channel settings and they seem to be enabled: http://d.pr/sYS1 and its a single entry.. I created the page by oging to Content > Publish > Personal Trainer Directory and filled out the fields there.. same process I used for blog posts

Comment: Can you give an example of the URL? You can leave out the domain name. I just need the part after the domain.  Thank you!

Comment: site.com/index.php/personal-trainer-directory/brian-smith